# running SpringBootTest using a spring profile given by maven

Tags: spring-boot, maven, maven-3, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I got the following profile in my maven pom:

```
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>local</id>
                <build>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                            <configuration>
                                <profiles>
                                    <profile>local</profile>
                                </profiles>
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </build>
        </profile>
    <profile>
```

which is fine for starting application, but if i want to build the application as follow
`mvn clean install -Plocal` 
my `@SpringBootTest` fails due to:

```
No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
```

also tried:

```
        <profile>
            <id>local</id>
                <build>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                            <configuration>
                                <argLine>-Dspring.profiles.active=local</argLine>
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </build>
        </profile>
```

what am I missing?

ps `mvn spring-boot:run -Plocal` works no problem there ...
also no intrested in
`mvn clean install -Dspring.profiles.active=local` i know this works but just not intrested as profiles contain more than just profiles for us!

Comment: Why using a spring boot profile related to a maven profile. Does not make sense... if you like to start an spring boot app with a profile use the command line via `--spring.profiles.active=XXX` ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Your) Spring-boot-maven-plugin (configuration) is not affected by "install" target (it involves only spring-boot:repackage, which is not aware of "active profiles"/this config), that is why your profile (though propagated) not activated in your tests.

If you want it to work for `mvn install`, you will have to pass:

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=local
```

to:

- surefire-plugin

  in pom(>profile>build>plugins):

  ```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <argLine>-Dspring.profiles.active=local</argLine>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  ```

  or via cmd. [See also.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53216090/592355) [Plugin-Doc](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#argLine).
- failsafe-plugin ... analogous!;) [Plugin-Doc](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#argLine).
- maybe more... (any other plugin, which starts spring-boot.)

---

- But of course, please don't "forget" about [`@ActiveProfiles`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ActiveProfiles.html), which activates(more precisely adds!) profiles to your test( classe)s. (but build independent;)
- And (of course;) you can also "package" `spring.profiles.active` somewhere in your application (properties/any location), in (almost) any "maven build".

  e.g. :

  - pom.xml:

    ```
     <profile>
      <id>local</id>
      <properties>
        <myProfiles>local,foo,bar</myProfiles>
      </properties>
     </profile>
     <!-- ... and (outside/in default profile!) -->
     <build>
      <testResources>
        <testResource>
          <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
          <filtering>true</filtering>
        </testResource>
      </testResources>
      <!-- ... -->
    </build>
    ```
  - src/test/resources/application.properties:

    ```
     spring.profiles.active=${myProfiles}
    ```
  - would write into target/test-classes/application.properties:

    ```
     spring.profiles.active=local,foo,bar
    ```

    ..., which would be (hopefully) picked up & activated by the "next test".

Comment: had tried maven-failsafe-plugin but did not work.
 however maven-failsafe-plugin did work thx

Comment: for failsafe (if you have/use it): `local` is probably not suiting.

Comment: Added an example of what I tried for fail safe. local is just for testing(like foo or bar), unless it is being skipped in fail safe?

Comment: failsafe-plugin is also not affected by `mvn clean install` (surefire *is*), for that you have to `mvn integration-test`. ;)